# TokenAccountNotFoundError with getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount Typescript

Tags: web3.js, spl-token-program, mint, typescript

I am trying to simulate minting 100 tokens to a wallet address and when I start the program, I get thrown this error:
`TokenAccountNotFoundError`
This is the typescript code for creating the token account:

```
  connection: web3.Connection,
  payer: web3.Keypair,
  mint: web3.PublicKey,
  owner: web3.PublicKey
) {
  const tokenAccount = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      payer,
      mint,
      owner,
  )
  
  console.log(
      `Token Account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${tokenAccount.address}?cluster=devnet`
  )

  return tokenAccount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` transaction is just sent but not fully confirmed before the mint transaction is sent.
You should wait until trnasction is confirmed.

I am not sure what the token object you used is but the default `createAssociatedTokenAccount` in @solana/spl-token library confirms transaction internally.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7/token/js/src/actions/createAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L41